# Pointing 3 domains to same Django app and using different urls to serve each

Tags: nginx, django

So I have three domains and three subdirectories in my django app.

lets say my IP is x.x.x.x

I want the app to work like this:

```
url_visited_by_the_user
content_served_from

www.domain1.com/
x.x.x.x/dir1/

www.domain1.com/bla/bla/
x.x.x.x/dir1/bla/bla/

www.domain2.com/
x.x.x.x/dir2/

www.domain2.com/bla/bla/
x.x.x.x/dir2/bla/bla/

www.domain3.com/
x.x.x.x/dir3/

www.domain3.com/bla/bla/
x.x.x.x/dir3/bla/bla/
```

I dont want the user to see dir1, dir2, etc. I am using Nginx. Any ideas how this can be done?

Duplicate from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978070/pointing-3-domains-to-same-django-app-and-using-different-urls-to-serve-each). was asked to ask this on server fault.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup multiple `server` blocks and define a `root` path for each. Do this inside your nginx config file.

```
server {

        listen   80;
        server_name www.domain1.com;
        root /x.x.x.x/dir1/;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        // other configurations
}
server {

        listen   80;
        server_name www.domain2.com;
        root /x.x.x.x/dir2/;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        // other configurations
}
server {

        listen   80;
        server_name www.domain3.com;
        root /x.x.x.x/dir3/;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        // other configurations
}
```